KafkaListener not working after a while (Micronaut)
I'm using Kafka to communicate multiple microservices. Basically I have a microservice that registers entities and then publishes them as a message to Kafka for listeners to consume and sync. The problem I'm having is that for some reason, after a while some KafkaListeners stop working on some microservices. I did some validations and the problem does not seem to be publication because I have a KafkaMagic instance with which I can validate the correct publication of the message and its content. The strange thing about it all is that I realized that by simply modifying the name of the listener class, it automatically starts working again and even begins to consume the messages that it had ignored before. For example: if the listener has the name "PatientListener" and it does not work, simply changing it to "PatientListenerX" will solve the problem. However, this is a temporary solution because after a while they stop working again. I don't know if it is a microservices problem or a Kafka configuration problem as such.
I use Kakfa using a docker container with other dependencies.
Below I show you the content of docker-compose and the configurations that I have in consumer microservice.
This is my docker-compose for Kafka:
version: '3.5'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181 # <1>
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092 # <2>
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:4.1.1
    hostname: schema-registry
    ports:
    - "38081:38081"
    depends_on:
    - kafka
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: zookeeper:2181
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://schema-registry:38081
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEBUG: "true"

  kafka-rest:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:4.1.1
    hostname: kafka-rest
    ports:
    - "38082:38082"
    depends_on:
      - schema-registry
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: schema-registry:38081
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: kafka-rest
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: http://kafka-rest:38082

This is my configuration for consumer in application.yml:
kafka:
  bootstrap:
    servers: ${KAFKA_HOST:`localhost:9092`}
  enabled: true
  producers:
    default:
      retries: ${KAFKA_RETRIES:5}
      retry.backoff.ms: ${KAFKA_RETRY_BACKOFF:3000}

And this is my KafkaListener:
@KafkaListener
public class SpecificTaskMedicalRecordsListener {
    private final ManualTenantResolver manualTenantResolver;
    private final SpecificTaskService specificTaskService;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    public SpecificTaskMedicalRecordsListener(
        ManualTenantResolver manualTenantResolver, SpecificTaskService specificTaskService) {
        this.manualTenantResolver = manualTenantResolver;
        this.specificTaskService = specificTaskService;
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }


    @Topic("core-specific-task-save")
    public void save(KafkaRequest<SpecificTaskResponse> kafkaRequest) {
        SpecificTaskRequest request = objectMapper.convertValue(kafkaRequest.getResponse(), SpecificTaskRequest.class);
        manualTenantResolver.setManualTenant(LogUtil.getTenancyFromToken(kafkaRequest.getToken()));
        specificTaskService.save(request);
    }
}

The Micronaut dependency used is this:
implementation('io.micronaut.kafka:micronaut-kafka:4.5.0')


I really appreciate your help.
The tests I have carried out have been those that I mentioned about changing names. But this is a temporary solution. Furthermore, I have not detected a time pattern to know when I should go ahead and change the name to avoid the error. I thought maybe it could be a cache problem but I don't know how to validate it.
What I need is for the KafkaListeners to be able to consume the messages without any problem.

What exactly stops working? Network connections? Sounds like you'll need to debug more with JMX metrics or TCP dump. BTW, Kafka doesn't need Zookeeper anymore
